# descargar archivos desde varios servidores sftp al mismo tiempo

Tags: python, ssh

Hola necesito descargar archivos desde varios (12) servidores SFTP, quisiera realizar las conexiones al mismo tiempo ya que los archivos pesan alrededor de 500MB c/u,  el ancho de banda en principio no es limitante, pero querría minimizar el tiempo en descargar todos los archivos.
Estuve experimentando un poco con la librería threading con el siguiente código.

```
import paramiko
import threading

servers_bsc = [
    {
        'server': 'server1.example.com',
        'username': 'username1',
        'password': 'password1',
        'remote_path': '/path/to/file1.txt',
        'local_path': '/local/path/file1.txt'
    },
    {
        'server': 'server2.example.com',
        'username': 'username2',
        'password': 'password2',
        'remote_path': '/path/to/file2.txt',
        'local_path': '/local/path/file2.txt'
    },
    # siguen los demás servidores  
    ]


   def download_file(server):

       hostname = server["hostname"]
       username = server["username"]
       password = server["password"]
       remote_path = server["remote_path"]
       local_path = server["local_path"]

       client = paramiko.SSHClient()
       client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
       client.connect(hostname, username=username, password=password)
       sftp = client.open_sftp()
       try: # verifico si existe el archivo 
          files = sftp.listdir(remote_path)
          sftp.get(server['remote_path'], server['local_path'])
          sftp.close()

       except:
           print(f'NO EXISTE EL ARCHIVO {server["remote_path"]}')


   threads = []

   for server in servers_bsc:
       thread = threading.Thread(target=download_file, args=(server,))
       thread.start()
       threads.append(thread)

   # Esperar a que todos los hilos terminen
   for thread in threads:
          thread.join()
```

Como prueba solo dejo 1 server con el archivo, el cual veo que lo empieza a descargar, pero una vez que termina de descargar los 500MB y considerando que los demás entrarían en el except "NO EXISTE EL ARCHIVO", noto que el script nunca termina! queda haciendo "algo"  pero nunca termina! queda el código corriendo...

Estoy fallando en algún concepto en el manejo de hilos (es mi primera incursión en  Multithreading/ Multiprocessing / Async)? alguien realizo algo similar? o trabajo con alguna librería como asyncio o multiprocessing para algo similar?  me podrían indicar/sugerir que librería utilizar y/o cual es mas conveniente para estos casos de usos...
desde ya gracias por su tiempo... saludos